# Stuck in x87 FLD instruction

Tags: disassembly, objdump, amd64

I've been working for my final project which is a disassembler for AMD64 instruction set, and i was trying to disassemble machine code by hand to understand it correctly. But i got stuck at a x87 instruction.

Machine code of instruction is: `dd 04 c5 60 40 08 08...`

I've checked AMD64 manual vol3, and it says DD is an x87 instruction and with the help of ModRM byte ,which is `0b00000100`, my ModRM.reg field is `000` and with this information manual says this instructions meaning is "FLD mem64real". But since I've compiled this code for i386 target architecture i think that i shouldn't have 64 bit memory adress.

But the most interesting part is when i checked the binary with objdump, it says that this bytes are corresponds to `fldl   0x8084060(,%eax,8)` but i can't find any information about FLDL instruction nor how does objdump find this.

So my question is am i doing something wrong ?

How objdump think that instruction is FLDL but manual says its FLD ?

Target machine of binary is i386.

I use AMD64 manual volume 3 to check instructions

Version of objdump is `GNU objdump (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.26.1`

Here is readelf output of binary

```
ELF Header
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF32
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
Machine:                           Intel 80386
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x80482c0
Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          3744 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         8
Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         31
Section header string table index: 28
```

Comment: "For example, fld[lst] means fldl, flds, or fldt; fst{ls} means fst, fstl, or fsts; and fild{l|ll} means fild, fildl, or fildll." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4693/805-4693.pdf also http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FLD.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fldl` is just the [AT&T syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) for the "FLD" instruction involving a long (4 bytes) register. This is equivalent to

```
fld     qword ptr [eax*8 + 8084060h]
```

in Intel syntax.

You could [instruct objdump to emit Intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362630/how-can-objdump-emit-intel-syntax) with the `-M intel` flag.

---

While i386 does not support 64-bit addresses, it certain can read 64 bits out given an address. The "FLD m64fp" instruction reads 8 bytes from the input address (`0x8084060 + eax*8` in this case), interprets it as a floating point number (a `double`), and then pushes it to the FPU register stack.

In this case `0x8084060` is likely an address to a global array of `double` and `eax` is an index to fetch a value out of the array.

Comment: But where did `+eax*8` come from ? I know that DD means it's an x87 instruction and i use ModRM byte(04) to find it's `fld` and i think somehow c5 means `eax*8`. But i cannot find what is that C5 byte or which table i should look to find its values.

Answer (score 2):

So this answer only focuses on the second question of @Efe:
How is `+eax*8` constructed.

You can determine the SIB-offsets with the following steps. We analyze the first two bytes `04 c5` of the whole instruction:

```
dd 04 c5 60 40 08 08
```

First, we only focus on the MOD-REG-R/M Byte (look [here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0060_mod_reg_r_m_byte.htm) for details)

```
MOD-REG-R/M Byte = 04
--------------------------------------------------
04   0000 0100
MOD  00          Meaning: SIB with no displacement
REG  000         Meaning: eax (32-Bit)
R/M  100         Meaning: SIB with no displacement
```

Second, we analyze the SIB Byte of the instruction (look [here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0100_sib_byte_layout.htm) for details). Scaled indexed addressing mode uses the second byte (namely, SIB byte) that follows the MOD-REG-R/M.

```
SIB Byte = C5
--------------------------------------------------
c5    1100 0101
Scale 11    Meaning: Index*8
Index 000   Meaning: eax register
Base  101   Meaning: Displacement only
```

The combination of MOD and Base lead to (look [here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0110_scaled_indexed.htm) for details)

```
MOD = 00 and BASE field = 101:
--------------------------------------------------
disp + eax*n
```

Comment: I've totally got distracted with `mem64real` keyword in manual and forgot about that we determine memory address starting with ModRM.r/m field. Thanks for reminding me that